# Why is the banana flying slowly in QBasic Gorillas?

Tags: ms-dos, qemu

I'm playing QBasic Gorillas in MS-DOS 6.22 running in QEMU.

The problem is that the banana is flying really slowly (it takes few seconds between movements). But when I hold down any key, then banana flies like it did few decades ago, when I last played it in non-emulated environment. Where's the catch?

Source code is available here: http://www.jefflewis.net/archive/programming/gorilla.bas

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the answer can be found in delay loops. When you are holding down a key, you are providing input to the emulated environment, forcing QEMU to execute the emulated code more often (to react to the input, which in this case is ignored).

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think it is a programming question. I mean, I don't think it is a problem in the game and I don't want to "fix" the source code. I want to know why it behaves like this in an emulated environment, which in theory should be indistinguishable to the guest.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Indeed, changing Rest function to use fixed number of iterations instead of TIMER fixes the problem. Getting closer :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the commented lines at the beginning of the program. There's a constant called SPEEDCONST that sets the game speed, and its initial setting is way too low. It's set to 500; it should be > 10000